# How to get backgrid-paginator speak with spring controller for sorting

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, backbone.js, pagination, backgrid

We are using `backbone.paginator`;`backgrid`;`backgrid-filter` ;`backgrid-paginator` it works great  we have small issue when trying sort  - at `server side mode` -the grid by one (or more) of its columns

For Server side with are using `Spring` with `org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

When debugging the app it seems that the `order` from client side does NOT get parsed well on spring side and it falls to the `default value`

#### Two questions:

1. Does any one know what is the parameters that should be sent to `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`?
2. How can `Backbone.PageableCollection` can be tweak in order to achieve that?

#### Our Initialize Paginator Code

```
   Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
            state : {
                pageSize : 15,
                firstPage : 0, /* Spring paging is 0-based */
            },

            mode : "server",
        
            /**
             * override default queryParams to fit spring pageable var names
             */
            queryParams : {
                    pageSize:"size",
                    totalRecords:"totalElements",
                    sortKey:"sort",
                    order:"sort_order",
                    directions  : { "-1": "asc", "1": "desc" }
            },
  })
```

P.S:

It seems that `spring` expect to get the `data` as array separated by `comma` instead regular. any idea how to it with `backbone.paginator`? or how to change spring to be able to parse paginator to support several of `sorting parameters`.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some digging at Spring source `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and at `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java` (can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java)) it Seems that Spring expect sort parameters to be with the format of

```
sort="column1,column2,column3...,order"&sort="column4,column5,...,order"
```

It seems that `backbone.paginator` does not support multiply ordering but in order to make `paginator` to support  `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` with singal ordering, one can override `sync` function to setup the vars.

### Example

```
var sync = Backbone.PageableCollection.prototype.sync;

Backbone.PageableCollection.prototype.sync = function(method, model,
        options) {
    options.type = 'POST' // this help with unicode on tomcat and can be removed..

    /**
     * @override sync Add some code to support parsing of sorting parameters
     *           by SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver
     */
    if (!options.data) {
        sync.apply(this, arguments)
    }

    var sortKey = _.result(this.queryParams,"sortKey");

    if (!sortKey in options.data) {
        sync.apply(this, arguments)
    }

    options.data[STR_SPRING_SORT] = options.data[sortKey]
    var orderKey = _.result(this.queryParams,"order");

    var STR_SPRING_SORT = "sort";
    var STR_SEPERATOR = ",";

    if (orderKey  in options.data) {
        options.data[STR_SPRING_SORT] = options.data[STR_SPRING_SORT] + STR_SEPERATOR
                + options.data[orderKey]
        if (sortKey !== STR_SPRING_SORT) {
            delete options.data[sortKey];
        }

        delete options.data["order"];
    }

    sync.apply(this, arguments);

};
```

### Remark

One can force spring to change the `comma` and the `sort` string.